# Can the receiver of an IR sensor pick up the signal from another IR sensor?

Tags: infrared-radiation, sensor

So I was trying to find a way to transmit a particular signal.

I was thinking of getting one IR sensor to transmit a signal, which would be picked up by the receiver of another IR sensor. However, as far as I know, IR sensors are generally meant to receive their own signals (by reflection or some other related returning of waves).

Is it thus feasible to use the transmitter of one and the receiver of the other? Will there be any issues in doing so?

Comment: This is exactly what a TV remote does.

Comment: If one device is creating the signal and another device is receiving it, the first device isn't a sensor, it's a transmitter.

Comment: @M.Enns Would it be possible with something like this: https://www.electronicscomp.com/ir-sensor-module-india?gclid=CjwKCAiAvK2bBhB8EiwAZUbP1GlSWWiu_xq2s-0Zi4HQr8YRwbmWx4FB1ZZXG3oA7Zs7sBIdtosCzxoClU8QAvD_BwE

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.